# Behavior of shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD) with TCP

Tags: networking, sockets, network-programming, tcp

When using a TCP socket, what does

```
shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD);
```

actually do? Does it just make all `recv()` calls return an error code? If so, which error code?

Does it cause any packets to be sent by the underlying TCP connection? What happens to any data that the other side sends at this point - is it kept, and the window size of the connection keeps shrinking until it gets to 0, or is it just discarded, and the window size doesn't shrink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shutting down the read side of a socket will cause any blocked `recv` (or similar) calls to return `0` (indicating graceful shutdown).  I don't know what will happen to data currently traveling up the IP stack.  It will most certainly ignore data that is in-flight from the other side.  It will not affect writes to that socket at all.

In fact, judicious use of `shutdown` is a good way to ensure that you clean up as soon as you're done.  An HTTP client that doesn't use keepalive can shutdown the write-side as soon as it is done sending the request, and a server that sees `Connection: closed` can likewise shutdown the read-side as soon as it is done receiving the request.  This will cause any further erroneous activity to be immediately obvious, which is very useful when writing protocol-level code.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the Linux source code, `shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD)` doesn't seem to cause any state changes to the socket. (Obviously, `shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR)` causes `FIN` to be set.)

I can't comment on the window size changes (or lack thereof). But you can write a test program to see. Just make your `inetd` run a `chargen` service, and connect to it. :-)

Answer (score 5):

shutdown(,SHUT_RD) does not have any counterpart in TCP protocol, so it is pretty much up to implementation how to behave when someone writes to a connection where other side indicated that it will not read or when you try to read after you declared that you wont.

On slightly lower level it is beneficial to remember that TCP connection is a pair of flows using which peers send data until they declare that they are done (by SHUT_WR which sends FIN). And these two flows are quite independent.

Answer (score 5):

It has two effects, one of them platform-dependent.

1. `recv()` will return zero, indicating end of stream.
2. Any further writes to the connection by the peer will either be (a) silently thrown away by the receiver (BSD), (b) be buffered by the receiver and eventually cause `send()` to block or return -1/`EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` (Linux), or (c) cause the receiver to send an RST (Windows).

Comment: I tested this scenario on the Linux OS with a Python program. The receiver buffered the data, and the receiver will get the data from buffer by calling 'recv()' again. Very confusing!

Comment: @翟桂锋 I would consider that a bug in Linux if true. I tested this around 2002 on all these platforms and it worked as described here.

Comment: Yes，you're right. The receiver buffered the data  cause the sender's send() to block(TCP receive window is 0). But if the receiver call recv() again, then everything changed. the receiver can get the data, and the sender can send more data again. Just as @TonyYu said.

Answer (score 5):

I test `shudown(sock,SHUT_RD)` on Ubuntu 12.04. I find that when you call `shutdown(sock,SHUT_RD)` if there are no any type of data(include FIN....) in the TCP buffer, the successive read call will `return 0`(indicates end of stream). But if there are some data which arrived before or after shutdown function, read call will process normally as if shutdown function was not called. It seems that `shutdown(sock,SHUT_RD)` doesn't cause any TCP states changed to the socket

Answer (score 0):

shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD) causes any writer to the socket to receive a sigpipe signal.

Any further reads using the read system call will return a -1 and set errno to EINVAL.

The use of recv will return a -1 and set errno to indicate the error (probably ENOTCONN or ENOTSOCK).

Comment: why would SHUT_RD affect writers?  I don't see any obvious reason for it to do so (though, I suppose I always use MSG_NOSIGNAL, so that may have an impact).

Comment: Because (quoting from Wikipedia) "On POSIX-compliant platforms, SIGPIPE is the signal sent to a process when it attempts to write to a pipe without a process connected to the other end."  And the shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD) statement disconnects the reader process from the pipe.  To add injury to insult, the default action upon receipt of a SIGPIPE signal is for the process (i.e the writer) to terminate.

Comment: This is not correct. Any further reads will cause recv() to rerun zero, indicating end of stream.