# Properly 2 TcpStream

Tags: rust, tcp

I am working on a TCP proxy server where a client connects to it and it starts a new connection to a backend and forward all packets (bidirectional). The function that handles this part looks like this.

```rust
pub fn route(source: TcpStream, worker: Worker) -> Result<()> {
    // `source` and `destination` are both `TcpStream`
    let mut source = source;
    let mut destination = TcpStream::connect(worker.address)?;

    let mut source_copy = source.try_clone()?;
    let mut destination_copy = destination.try_clone()?;
    let src2dst = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        std::io::copy(&mut source_copy, &mut destination_copy).unwrap();
    });

    let dst2src = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        std::io::copy(&mut destination, &mut source).unwrap();
        // source.shutdown(Shutdown::Both).unwrap(); <--- if this line is commented, it will stuck
    });

    src2dst.join().unwrap();
    dst2src.join().unwrap();
    Ok(())
}
```

However, in its current form, this function will stuck. In particular, if I shutdown the `source` when destination stops writing, it won't block. But I am still not sure why this works (or why it does not). I am currently using it only to proxy HTTP traffic, and it does not appear to have problems. But I am not sure if it works for generic TCP. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`std::io::copy` reads from the reader until it gets an end-of-file condition. The way to signal an end-of-file condition on a TCP connection is to send a `FIN` packet, which is realized in software by calling `shutdown` to shut down the write half of the connection.

HTTP allows reusing a single connection to send multiple requests, one after the other. There is enough information in a request for the recipient to determine where the request ends, and likewise for responses. In your case, it appears the backend shuts down its write half of the connection, which causes your `io::copy` to return. If the HTTP response has [`Connection: close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) in its headers, then you *must* shut down the write half, or else the client will hang waiting for the response body because it never receives a `FIN` packet.

TL;DR: When the copy from A to B returns normally, you should shut down the write half of B to forward the end-of-file condition (`FIN` packet). This goes for the copies in *both* directions, and is valid for TCP in general. Shutting down the read half of sockets doesn't appear to be necessary (it doesn't generate any TCP packets).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did some experimentation, and [this](https://gist.github.com/lewisxy/ce698e31233c65fdc791c7b882cd5f41) is what I found to work for generic TCP . It's very similar to what you mentioned, the only difference being that I use `Shutdown::Both` instead. In this case, what is the difference between `Shutdown::Both` and `Shutdown::Write`?

Comment: `Both` combines the effects of `Write` and `Read`. [The effects of `Read` are not super clear or consistent across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/740817/234590), but one common theme is that it will cause reads to return as if a `FIN` packet was received, even if the other end didn't shutdown its write half. I can't say I'm familiar enough with such low-level socket operations (every time I use sockets, I get something wrong and learn something new) that I can say if shutting down the read half is a good practice or not.