# Force blocking BIO_read of OpenSSL to return

Tags: c++, openssl, blocking

Working with OpenSSL is completely new to me. I have taken over an existing implementation and have the following problem:

BIO_read and BIO_write of my client app work Blocking and therefore run in separate threads. The server app is from an external vendor and its implementation cannot be changed.

How to force BIO_read to return when it is waiting for data and the associated thread should be killed to close the connection to the server? I have tried BIO_ssl_shutdown but it does not work.

Comment: As for the manual *BIO_read() ... should be combined with non blocking I/O*

Comment: Shutdown the socket for input.

Comment: @273K: I rather interpret the manual in a way that the combination with select() should be avoided. I do not see a general discouragement of blocking mode.

Comment: @user207421: Do you mean BIO_closesocket? That's my current solution, but it feels wrong.

Comment: It is not interpretation of the manual. It's requirement if you want non blocking BIO_read and BIO_write.

Comment: user207421 meant [`shutdown()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740817/behavior-of-shutdownsock-shut-rd-with-tcp) socket.

Comment: @273K: No, the functions are supposed to work blocking. I have updated my question to make this clearer.

Comment: According to the manual, BIO_reset() should be called. SSL_shutdown() just closes a TLS session and does not shutdown an underlying TCP connection. *Calling BIO_reset() on an SSL BIO closes down any current SSL connection by calling SSL_shutdown(). BIO_reset() is then sent to the next BIO in the chain: this will typically disconnect the underlying transport. <...> BIO_ssl_shutdown() closes down an SSL connection on BIO chain bio. It does this by locating the SSL BIO in the chain and calling SSL_shutdown() on its internal SSL pointer.*

Comment: BIO_reset() works, but similar to BIO_closesocket(), the other side (server) doesn't seem to quite get along with this sledgehammer method. Also the TCP traces do not look correct. 
Calling shutdown() seems to be the correct solution. The TCP traces look correct (FIN->ACK, FIN->ACK) and the server seems to be happy. Thanks to both of you for the help. @user207421: If you post your comment as an answer, I can mark the question as solved.