# What is the correct way to close a raw socket in python?

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I have a script that creates raw PACKET sockets to capture all incoming traffic, and I want to make sure that when the script finishes, the sockets are closed.
From python socket documentation, I understand that shutdown() and close() methods should be used to close a socket *in a timely fashion*.
However, I guess that for this type of socket, SHUT_RD, SHUT_WR and SHUT_RDWR modes can not be used, which renders shutdown() unusable.

On occasions, when I used close() only, the script hanged and I had to wait for it a lot, for the socket to actually close.
My question is: On Linux, how can I close a raw socket immediately, if I no longer need it?

Comment: What do you expect to happen technically when you close a raw socket?

Comment: @KlausD. I expect that socket to no longer exist. For instance, if I issue ss -0 in the terminal, I expect to not see the socket opened by my script.

Comment: The following link might help.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740817/behavior-of-shutdownsock-shut-rd-with-tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740817/behavior-of-shutdownsock-shut-rd-with-tcp)

Comment: Shutdown is something specific for TCP sockets (and maybe others), not a generic operation on all kinds of sockets